# how to fixe sass command line not find

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

hi I'm new using sass and I'm using vs code sass liver compiler, the first day when I install the ass extension live compiler it was working perfectly but the next day when I open my vscode and try to continue where I left I can't do anything sass or CSS is completely block the only message that I received is command line not find I have to create another folder in order to start a new project and that way  it will start working but the next day when I open it wants so I'm asking if there is a command-line that I should type in order to continue where I left using vscode extension please i really need a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would go ahead and verify all your installations are active. For example, ensure 'Live Sass Compiler' is active in your environment. You can simply tell this by looking at the bottom of VSCode and clicking the 'Watch Sass' button (as show below):

[image]

If the compiler is properly formatted I would go ahead and uninstall and reinstall the extension just to be safe. It will format and reapply itself to any of your .scss files.

Next, I would go ahead and reinstall SASS but ensure you install it globally. I will asume you are using Node.js and NPM in your command-line.

```
npm install -g sass
```

If your problems still persist follow up with a post of your project or perhaps some screenshots of your error messages.